# Hosting flask using port triggering

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I have hosted a flask server on my Ubuntu PC. The server is running on 5000 port. The PC is connected with a WiFi, and I can access the page using my mobile in the same WiFi network. The server is made using Python and Flusk API.

Now I want to do port forwarding so that my friends can see this website. However, accessing my router admin page, I see that there is no port forwarding option. Rather, there is port triggering option. I am using DLink Dir615 with Hardware version:T3    Firmware version: 20.22.
It looks like the following:

[image]

How to configure it so that my friends can see my website? I am a newbie on networking.

I have added the following rules, but https://canyouseeme.org/ cannot find my server at port 5000

[image]

Virtual Server setup

[image]

Comment: It's basically the same thing. [Port Triggering](https://portforward.com/help/porttriggering.htm)

Comment: In your case, what you to do is go to Virtual Server. Full instructions at [Fastest Way to Forward Ports on the D-Link DIR-615 Router](https://portforward.com/d-link/dir-615/v20/)

Comment: @DavidPostill Please see the edit. I have added the rules but still no result.

Comment: @DavidPostill Please see the current edit. I have added Virtual Server

Comment: OK. Now you need to see if your ISP is using [Carrier Grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT). Please read [Alternatives to Port Forwarding & NAT](https://portforward.com/help/alt-to-pf.htm): "There are four major problems that you may run into that would require alternatives to port forwarding

Comment: Did you delete the port triggering rules?

Comment: @DavidPostill No, the port triggering rules are still there.

Comment: Delete them. You can't have both.

Comment: What is your public IP address? Does it start with 100.64?

Comment: It is 103.60.175.91

Comment: I have delete the port triggering rules, still not working

Comment: Then your ISP may be blocking the ports so you cannot run servers at home. Speak to your ISP.